# Sitecore Custom Control - Update based on values from a second control

Tags: controls, sitecore

I need to create a new type of control in Sitecore.  Our CE would like to be able to make cards filter based on a location.  To do this, we have created three lists of locations: states, countries, and South America locations.  Each locations are a folder in sitecore, with a list of name/value pair items underneath, representing the locations.

Ex:

- States

  - Alaska
  - Arizona
  - Arkansas
  - ...
- Countries

  - Canada
  - USA
  - ...
- South America Locations

  - Brazil
  - Peru
  - Chile

When the CE adds the component to the page, they should get a treelist to allow them to select the 'location' list folder.  Once they select that folder, the list of items under
that location folder should be displayed in a multiselect list.

The problem is I cant figure out how to refresh the multiselect list based on the 'location' list folder selected.  Right now, when the component works, the correct list of states are loaded in the multiselect, but if I chose countries, the list of countries does not get loaded.

Here's basically what I have now:

```
public class DynamicMultilist : MultilistEx
{
    private void RenderList(Guid listItemGuid)
    {
        Item listItem = GetListItem(listItemGuid, "master");
        this.Source = string.Format("query:{0}/*", listItem.Paths.FullPath);
        // ... Instantiate html writer
        DoRender(writer);
    }

    protected override void DoRender(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
        base.DoRender(output);
    }

    public override void HandleMessage(Message message)
    {
        if (message.Name == "datacontext:changed")
        {
            string guid = (message.Sender as DataContext).Folder;
            // ... Convert string above to Item
            RenderList(listItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I came across a similar requirement a few years ago, there was no way to achieve this with two separate fields because CE controls do not know anything about each other.

One of the options you can try though is using the `Droptree`, `Grouped Droplink` or `Treelist` field type that would display the tree structure. Try them and see which one works better for your amount of entries. This approach will allow you to store only the selected child item IDs while showing the grouped view to Content Editors. If I understood your content structure correctly, you will be able to identify the parent folder ID from the selected child item in the code even though it will not be stored in a dedicated field.